# Valor padrão do Input no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

No `Laravel`, quero que, quando um determinado valor não exista no `Input`, eu possa definir um valor padrão.

Com PHP puro, é possível fazer assim:

```
$text = isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : 'padrão';
```

No Laravel sei que é possível fazer de uma forma parecida, algo assim:

```
 $text = Input::has('text') ? Input::get('text') : 'padrão';
```

Tendo em vista que o `Laravel` é um excelente frameworks com alguns recursos que diminuem a reescrita continua de códigos, existe um jeito mais fácil de se obter um valor parão para um valor do input? Ou esse é o único jeito que existe?

Pois as vezes fica cansativo ficar fazendo:

```
$a = Input::has('a') ? Input::get('a') : 'Valor padrão';
$b = Input::has('b') ? Input::get('b') : 'Valor padrão';
$c = Input::has('c') ? Input::get('c') : 'Valor padrão';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar dessa forma `Input::get('nome_campo','valor');` no caso o segundo parâmetro identifica o valor padrão caso o Input retorne null.

Answer (score 2):

O Laravel inclui um helper que faz exatamente isso:

```
array_get($array, 'campo', 'valor padrão'); // null como default
```

A vantagem é que você pode fazer isso em qualquer lugar, não necessariamente somente no `input`.

Particularmente, não gosto do `array_get`, sou mais o operador [Null coalescing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) do PHP 7.

Comment: Bem lembrado. Obrigado pela contribuição, nem todos sabem que a função array_get tem essa funcionalidade. É quase um easter egg.